# Fill big box with smaller boxes

Tags: mathematics, geometry, three-dimensional

Let's say we have a big box with inner edges with the lengths 2m, 1.5m, 1.4m.
Can we fill this with smaller boxes with the edge lengths of 3dm, 5dm and 1m, without any gaps?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your questions. If you wish to delete your posts (which will only hide them to users with less than 10k reputation), please instead click the "delete" link at the bottom left, under the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, easy:

> Turn all blocks upright and make two layers as follows:
>  [image]